# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (Iteration)

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, eof

I am getting error while running this part of the code. tried some of the existing solutions.

```
import optimizers.GA as ga
import benchmarks
import csv
import numpy
import time
import warnings
import os
import plot_convergence as conv_plot
import plot_boxplot as box_plot
warnings.simplefilter(action="ignore")
def selector(algo, func_details, popSize, Iter):
    function_name = func_details[0]
    lb = func_details[1]
    ub = func_details[2]
    dim = func_details[3]
    if algo == "GA":
     x = ga.GA(getattr(benchmarks, function_name), lb, ub, dim, popSize, Iter)
    else:
        return null
    return x
def run(optimizer, objectivefunc, NumOfRuns, params, export_flags):
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, your `run` function at the bottom has no body. Is this all your code?

Comment: Also,  your indentation in the if/else block is inconsistent, in case that isn't just a result of bad formatting in the SO post.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't wrote anything within the function `run`.
Try This:-

```python
def run(optimizer, objectivefunc, NumOfRuns, params, export_flags):
    pass
```

Comment: so what should i do to import data into the function? thanks sir

Comment: use the global function or import them as attributes.

Comment: do you have a global function about genetic algorithm sir?